# Python chromedriver WebDriverException: invalid argument

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I just updated my chromedriver to newest version from https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads (ChromeDriver 79.0.3945.16) and when I try to launch webdriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'path/to/file')
```

I get error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: invalid argument: 'firstMatch' must contain at least one entry
```

What does this mean? I also tried couple other versions, but got same error. I don't know what version I was using before but it was maybe 1 year old version or something and didn't throw that exception.

I am using python 3.5.1

Comment: Chromedriver v79 is currently for the Chrome Beta v79. Do you have actually have Chrome Beta installed ?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.My chrome version is Version 78.0.3904.97.Please suggest a solution